# analytics.js creating tracker including 'allowLinker' & 'useAmpClientId'

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I have a site that has cross-domain tracking and recently added new AMP functionality.

I wanted to ask you if next tracker creation is wrong?

```
ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'useAmpClientId': true});
```

or I should use something like:

```
    ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true, 'useAmpClientId': true});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **[The create method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#the_create_method)**
>
> The analytics.js library provides a variety ways to create trackers,
>   but the most common way is to use the create command and pass the
>   tracking ID and cookie domain fields as the second and third
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
> ```
>
> **Naming trackers**
>
> You may also, optionally, name the tracker by passing the name field
>   as the fourth argument in the create command. Naming a tracker is
>   necessary in cases where you need to create more than one tracker for
>   the same page. For more details on why you might need to do this, see
>   the section below on working with multiple trackers.
>
> ```
> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'myTracker');
> ```
>
> Creating a tracker without setting the name field is known as creating
>   a "default" tracker. A default tracker is internally given the name
>   "t0".

Comment: noogui - Thank you for the answer. Not sure that I understand you on 100%. Do you mean that I should name both trackers in the first code? Also the second: is it wrong? Do u mind to provide example for mine situation that is correct in you opinion?

Answer (score -1):

The second way is the rightway i.e.

```
ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true, 'useAmpClientId': true});
```

and for setup verification refer below link

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7486764